# $P(Y > \sqrt{3}X | Y > 0)$ with independent and normally distributed $X, Y$

Tags: probability, definite-integrals

Let $X, Y$ be iid $N(0, 1)$, what is $P(Y > \sqrt{3}X | Y > 0)$

Here's what I've done $P(Y > \sqrt{3}X | Y > 0) = P(Y > max(0, \sqrt{3}X)/P(Y>0) = 2 P(Y > max(0, \sqrt{3}X) = 2 \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1 - \Phi(max(\sqrt{3}x, 0)) \phi(x) dx = 2 - 2 \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(max(\sqrt{3}x, 0)) \phi(x) dx \\
= 2 - 2 \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{2} \phi(x) dx  - 2 \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \Phi(\sqrt{3}x) \phi(x) dx = \frac{3}{2} - 2 \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \Phi(\sqrt{3}x) \phi(x) dx$

But I'm rusty on my calculus, I don't know how to compute this integral, may be it involves double integral manipulation of some sorts

How to compute that integral, is there another way to solve this that bypasses this computation ?

Comment: The distribution of $(X,Y)$, namely $\mathcal{N}(0,I_2)$ is radial. More precisely the radius $R$ and the angular part $\theta$ are independent, and $\Theta$ is uniform on $[0,2\pi[$. Up to the null set $\{R=0\}$, the events you consider can be expressed in function of $\Theta$ only.

Comment: thanks @ChristopheLeuridan, could you explain more about this distribution in terms of $R$ and $\Theta$ or share some reference.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform

Comment: For an elementary proof you may see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4853138/1231520

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @Christophe Leuridan, for independent $X,Y \sim N (0,1)$, the probability can be given by

$$\mathbb P \left (Y>\sqrt{3}X \, \Big | \, Y>0 \right)=\mathbb P \left (R>0, \Theta>\arctan{\sqrt{3}} \, \Big | \, 0<\Theta < \pi \right)=\mathbb P \left ( \Theta>\frac{\pi}{3}\, \Big | \,0<\Theta < \pi \right)=\frac{2}{3}.$$

The polar coordinates $(R,\Theta)$ of $(X,Y)$ are independent with $\Theta \sim \text{Uniform}[0,2\pi[$ and $ R \sim \text{Rayleigh}(1)$. For a proof see the following question: [Polar coordinates (distance and angle) of a random point with independent and normally distributed Cartesian coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4853138/1231520).